# Vuelidate required champ input Email OR NumberMobile

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

i would like to know how I can validate the form once the phone number or email address has been completed.
I don't really understand how to use or with vualidate, I looked at the document and some forum I didn't find someone in the same case as me.
My code : https://www.noelshack.com/2022-27-5-1657285356-screen1.png

Error : http://www.noelshack.com/2022-27-5-1657285360-screen2.png

If anyone can help me please <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is several ways to do it, what you can do is to make email and phone to required BUT you have another property `hasProvidedAtLeastOneContact` that check if at least one of them has a value.

```js
<script>
import useVuelidate from '@vuelidate/core'
import { required, email } from '@vuelidate/validators'

import { helpers } from '@vuelidate/validators'

const phoneValidator = (value) => !helpers.req(value) || value.includes('01') // customize here your validator


export default {
  setup () {
    return { v$: useVuelidate() }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      firstName: 'Jack',
      lastName: 'Smith',
      contact: {
        email: '',
        phone: ''
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    hasProvidedAtLeastOneContact() {
        return !!this.contact.email || !!this.contact.phone
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async validate() {
        console.log(await this.v$.$validate())
    }
  },
  validations () {
    return {
      firstName: { required }, // Matches this.firstName
      lastName: { required }, // Matches this.lastName
      contact: {
        email: { email }, // Matches this.contact.email
        phone: { phoneValidator } // Matches this.contact.phone
      },
      hasProvidedAtLeastOneContact: {
        isTrue: (value) => value
      } // Matches this.hasProvidedAtLeastOneContact
    }
  }
}

</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <p>Form</p>
        <input v-model="firstName">
        <input v-model="lastName">
        <input v-model="contact.email">
        <input v-model="contact.phone">
        <button @click="checkValidation">Validate</button>
    </div>

</template>
```

You can also have a similar result with dynmamic rules
but I think it's a bit more complex
https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/examples.html#dynamic-validation-schema